# Randomly spawning an enemy

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am in the progress of making a small 2d game where the objective is to eat as much poop as possible, but I'm having trouble spawning the poop at random times. I want the poop to spawn at the enemy's y location but then shoot forwards like an rpg.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from numpy.random import rand

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('STINKY BEETLE')

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
game_running = True
pl_x = int(screen_width/10)
pl_y = int(screen_height/2)
pl_width = 80
pl_height = 40
pl_vel = 30
en_width = 80
en_height = 40
en_x = screen_width - screen_width/10 - en_width
en_y = int(screen_height/2)
en_yvel = -10
po_width = 50
po_height = 30
po_x = 720
po_y = en_y
po_xvel = 15

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while game_running:
    clock.tick(10)

    po_delay = rand(1)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 4 and pl_y > pl_vel:
                pl_y -= pl_vel

            elif event.button == 5 and pl_y < screen_height - pl_width:
                pl_y += pl_vel

    if po_delay < 0.01:
        poop(po_x, po_y)

    en_y += en_yvel
    if en_y <= 0 or en_y >= screen_height - en_height:
        en_yvel =- en_yvel

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (105, 255, 125), (pl_x, pl_y, pl_width, pl_height))
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 125, 115), (en_x, en_y, en_width, en_height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is anything working? It seems you call your `poop(po_x, po_y)` function during random frames, what does this `poop()` function do? How do you move the poop across the screen? If you explain in more detail what you have working now and what next step you are having trouble with we can more easily help you solve this issue!

Comment: I have tried several things like, if a randomly generated number is below a certain threshold it makes a show_poop variable. I had true and the poop function was just another failed attempt, where I tried to make a function with all the information about the poop in it, and then I would just call that function if the randomly generated number was below the threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mange multiple "poops", then you have to create a list. And each "poop" is an object (an instance of a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)).

Crate a class `Poop`, which can `update` the position and `draw` the poop:

```
class Poop:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y-h//2, w, h)
        self.vel = -15
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.vel
    def draw(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, (255, 200, 125), self.rect)

poops = []
```

Use a timer event to spawn the poops. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create an [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). The time is set  in milliseconds. Set a random time by [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) e.g. set a time between 0.5 and 4 seconds (of course you can choose your own time interval):

```py
min_time, max_time = 500, 4000 # 0.5 seconds to to 4 seconds
spawn_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(spawn_event, random.randint(min_time, max_time))
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to start at `pygame.USEREVENT`. In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event, which spawns the poops.

Create a new poop when the event occurs in the event loop and set a new random time:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # [...]
    if event.type == spawn_event:
        pygame.time.set_timer(spawn_event, random.randint(min_time, max_time))
        poops.append(Poop(en_x, en_y+en_yvel+en_height//2, 50, 30))
```

Change the positions of the poops in a loop and remove them from the list, if they leave the window on the left:

```py
for poop in poops[:]:
    poop.update()
    if poop.rect.right <= 0:
        poops.remove(poop)
```

Draw them ina loop

```py
for poop in poops:
    poop.draw(screen)
```

See the example:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('STINKY BEETLE')

class Poop:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y-h//2, w, h)
        self.vel = -15
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.vel
    def draw(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, (255, 200, 125), self.rect)

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
game_running = True
pl_x, pl_y = screen_width//10, screen_height//2
pl_width, pl_height, pl_vel = 80, 40, 30
en_width, en_height, en_yvel = 80, 40, -10
en_x, en_y,  = screen_width - screen_width//10 - en_width, screen_height//2

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

min_time, max_time = 500, 4000 # 0.5 seconds up to 4 seconds 
spawn_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(spawn_event, random.randint(min_time, max_time))
poops = []

while game_running:
    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 4 and pl_y > pl_vel:
                pl_y -= pl_vel
            elif event.button == 5 and pl_y < screen_height - pl_width:
                pl_y += pl_vel

        if event.type == spawn_event:
            pygame.time.set_timer(spawn_event, random.randint(min_time, max_time))
            poops.append(Poop(en_x, en_y+en_yvel+en_height//2, 50, 30))

    en_y += en_yvel
    if en_y <= 0 or en_y >= screen_height - en_height:
        en_yvel =- en_yvel

    for poop in poops[:]:
        poop.update()
        if poop.rect.right <= 0:
            poops.remove(poop)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for poop in poops:
        poop.draw(screen)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (105, 255, 125), (pl_x, pl_y, pl_width, pl_height))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 125, 115), (en_x, en_y, en_width, en_height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pygame's time module to randomly spawn enemies. I am assuming you are using OOP for this. Firstly, when initializing your enemy class record the time when it first spawns.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        # other code
```

Then you can calculate the amount of time that has passed since your enemy last spawened. You can do something like `now =  time.time()` in your main game loop and get the difference.

```
enemy = Enemy()
while True:
    now = time.time()
    time_passed = now - enemy.start()
```

Now you can use this `time_passed` as an argument to your `spawn_enemy()` function that you might create which might look something like this:

```
def spawn(self, t):
   counter = t % random.randint(1, 10)
   if counter >= 0 and counter <=  0.2:
       #spawn enemy
```

Call this function as `spawn(time_passed)`